# In Pycharm, why is my NLTK module not found when I installed it already with pip install. (Uninstalled Python 3.8 to 3.7 to install Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I was trying to start on a Chatbot project where I was trying to work with Tensorflow. Once i had realized that Tensorflow is not supported with Python 3.8, I uninstalled 3.8 and installed 3.7. Now I was able to pip install tensorflow on my command line. I had already installed NLTK with Python 3.8, but now when i type import nltk into my .py file, i get an error saying that the module was not found.
Why am i getting a "module not found" error when I had already successfully installed NLTK through the command line already?

Comment: You mentioned that Python 3.8 was uninstalled, why do you expect NLTK to stay if interpreter that NLTK had been installed on does not exist anymore?

Comment: @user2235698 ok so, how to fix it already? I have a similar problem too (without the uninstallation stuff).